# Issue with Swift programmatic auto-layout constraint

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I am simply using

```
toolBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

for setting up my topAnchor.

However, when I change the constant from 0 to an actual number, the console gives me

> [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

this error.
I am calling this constraint in `viewDidLoad` but changing it to `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or other parts do not solve the problem.

How do I fix this error?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Simply needed to put translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

Answer (score 1):

Because you create another one , you need to edit the current one

```
var topCon:NSLayoutConstraint!

topcon = toolBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 0)

topCon.isActive = true
```

Then play with constant

```
topCon.constant = // anyNumber
```

Comment: this does not fix the problem I still get [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

Comment: please post all context

Comment: "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600002ed0ff0 h=-&- v=--& Material.Toolbar:0x7fa723e09140'\Uc11c\Uc6b8 \Ubc84\Uc2a4 \Uc54c\Ub78c \Uc124\Uc815'.midX == UIView:0x7fa723f0f8d0.midX - 207  (active)>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600002ed1180 h=-&- v=--& Material.Toolbar:0x7fa723e09140'\Uc11c\Uc6b8 \Ubc84\Uc2a4 \Uc54c\Ub78c \Uc124\Uc815'.width == UIView:0x7fa723f0f8d0.width - 414   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002ed0730 H:|-(50)-[Material.Toolbar:0x7fa723e09140'\Uc11c\Uc6b8 \Ubc84\Uc2a4 \Uc54c\Ub78c \Uc124\Uc815']   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fa723f0f8d0 )>"

Comment: Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002ed0730 H:|-(50)-[Material.Toolbar:0x7fa723e09140'서울 버스 알람 설정']   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fa723f0f8d0 )>

Comment: the conflict between centerX , width , post the constraints